# Why am I getting different answers using different methods?

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, contest-math

**Question:**

$\sin x+\cos x=1+\sin x\cos x,$ then

A) $\sin(x+\fracπ4)=\frac1{√2}$

B) $\sin(x-\fracπ4)=\frac1{√2}$

C) $\cos(x+\fracπ4)=\frac1{√2}$

D) $\cos(x-\fracπ4)=\frac1{√2}$

**Method $1$:**

Let $\sin x+\cos x=t,$ then $1+2\sin x\cos x=t^2$

Therefore, $t=1+\frac{t^2-1}{2}$

$t^2-2t+1=0\implies t=1$

So, $\sin x+\cos x=1$, thus, options A) and D) are correct.

**Method $2$:**

Putting $\sin x=0$ in the given equation, I get $\cos x=1$, thus, $x=2nπ$. So, options A, C, D are correct.

Putting $\cos x=0$ in the given equation, I get $\sin x=1$, thus, $x=(4n+1)\fracπ2$. So, option B is also correct.

How to streamline the answers of both the methods?

Comment: In method $2$ you have an additional assumption, e.g. $\sin(x)=0$ which does *not* follow from the equation. This leads to an addition option. Same with $\cos(x)$.

Comment: Method 2 does not make sense. You cannot put $\sin x=0$ since there may be no $x$ for which $\sin x=0$ simultaneously satisfying the given equation.

Comment: Can you at least explain where Method 2 comes from? I have not seen it before and I don't "get it" from any perspective? Like... what's the logic behind it supposed to be? Why can't you "Let $\sin x = 0.4$" instead, for example, which will lead to different answers? So my current answer to the question is, "It isn't clear what "method 2" is".

Comment: @AdamRubinson, we may call it hit and try. Or, boundary value checking. Or, objective way of solving it (in exam with less time, if we are not able to think of substitution or or any other method). Or option elimination.

Comment: I don't care what you call it. Explain the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you cannot assume $\sin x = 0$ or $\cos x = 0$.  For instance, $\sin x = 0$ at $x = \pi$, but $\pi$ is not a solution of the equation $\sin x + \cos x = 1 + \sin x\cos x$.  Similarly, $\cos x = 0$ at $x = 3\pi/2$, but $x = 3\pi/2$ is also not a solution of the equation $\sin x + \cos x = 1 + \sin x\cos x$.

Here is another approach.
\begin{align*}
\sin x + \cos x & = 1 + \sin x\cos x\\
0 & = 1 - \sin x - \cos x + \sin x\cos x\\
0 & = 1 - \sin x - \cos x(1 - \sin x)\\
0 & = (1 - \sin x)(1 - \cos x)
\end{align*}
Since a product is equal to zero if and only if one of its factors is equal to zero,
\begin{align*}
1 - \sin x & = 0 & \text{or} & & 1 - \cos x & = 0\\
1 & = \sin x & & & 1 & = \cos x\\
\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z} & = x & & & 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z} & = x
\end{align*}
If $x = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi$, then equations A, B, and D are true.  If $x = 2m\pi$, then equations A, C, and D are true.  Thus, only equations A and D are true at all solutions of the equation $\sin x + \cos x = 1 + \sin x\cos x$.

Comment: Thank you, ....

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

Putting $\sin x=0$ gives me options A), C), D).

Putting $\cos x=0$ gives me options A), B), D).

That means options A), D) are always satisfied. Options B), D) not always.

And in any case, $\sin x=1$ and $\cos x=1$ are the only two possible solutions here.

Even in Method $1$, when I got $\sin x +\cos x=1$, the only solutions are $\sin x=1$ or $\cos x=1$.